# How to pan in Blender?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, blender

By using keyboard shortcuts, how do you pan an object in Blender on a Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+click and drag

Source: http://www.stanfordesp.org/media/uploaded/10_04/H801_BlenderControls.pdf

Comment: please fix the link. it's been moved